# Update Operators in Mule MongoDB Cloud Connector

Tags: mongodb, mule

Is it possible to use update operators (such as $set) in updates performed via the MongoDB Cloud Connector in Mule? I would like to perform an update-objects-using-map operation to add a field to matched objects, which already exist in my collection.
Currently, it is replacing all of the existing fields with the field I am trying to add. I need to add the $set operator to accomplish what I want.

Here is a sample config:

```
<mongo:update-objects-using-map config-ref="Mongo_DB"    doc:name="Mongo DB"   database="myDatabase" password="myPassword" username="myUser" collection="test_SalesInvoice"   multi="false" upsert="true">
    <mongo:query-attributes>
        <mongo:query-attribute key="Invoice">#[payload.Invoice]</mongo:query-attribute>
    </mongo:query-attributes>
    <mongo:element-attributes >
        <mongo:element-attribute key="Worked">yes</mongo:element-attribute>
    </mongo:element-attributes>
</mongo:update-objects-using-map>
```

Thank you!

Justin

Comment: there's a test for $set in update here https://github.com/mulesoft/mongo-connector/blob/e0830c029d27f1b29e9a53fb852b5d0cba9e08c6/src/test/java/org/mule/module/mongo/automation/testcases/UpdateObjectsUsingQueryMapTestCases.java#L60 it seems like you need to pass it "$set" as the update object, where you are passing the new field as top level object.   Here is an example of xml syntax for $set https://github.com/mulesoft/mongo-connector/blob/fad5b5cf0c239f8f540b2ed9f455c079494be762/demo/src/main/app/mongo-demo.xml#L43

Comment: Looking at examples and tests, it looks like you need to pass it `$set` as the top level element for update:

    <mongo:element-attribute key="$set">
      <mongo:element-attribute key="Worked">yes</mongo:element-attribute>
    </mongo:element-attribute>

There also appears to be an update-objects-by-function-using-map with function being `$set`:

   <mongo:update-objects-by-function-using-map collection="#[map-payload:aCollectionName]" upsert="true" multi="false" function="$set">
Don't have environment to test so can't tell you which one will work for you.

Comment: Ah, it seems update-objects-by-function-using-map may just do the trick! I'll do some more extensive testing and then update here. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for both of the responses here! Preliminary testing indicated that update-objects-by-function-using-map (as was suggested here) was indeed the answer, and hopefully this will be helpful for anyone else encountering this issue. However, my team changed directions to pursue a different solution entirely, so I did not test this solution out more rigorously.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mongo:update-objects-by-function-using-map collection="yourCollection" 
                                                    config-ref="MongoDatabase" doc:name="Update Object"
                                                    upsert="true" function="$set">
            <mongo:query-attributes>
                <mongo:query-attribute key="id">#[payload.id]</mongo:query-attribute>
            </mongo:query-attributes>
            <mongo:element-attributes>
               <mongo:element-attribute key="newField">#[payload.newFieldValue]</mongo:element-attribute></mongo:element-attributes>
        </mongo:update-objects-by-function-using-map>

id  : is the attribute that will match with the original object to be update
newField : its the name of the new attribute that u want to add to u object on mongodb
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, it is always better if you can provide a description of what the issue was and how your answer solves it. This is a suggestion for further improving this and future answers.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I no longer have an environment setup to test this solution, but what I remember of the solution indicates that this probably is close to what I needed. Hopefully others may find it helpful.

Comment: the description of the issue : a user want to update a list of object on mongoDb throw Mule ESB, its exactly like doing an (Update where ..) with SQL.